# hello i am writing a triggers and when i enter the table name where it is requested it sees it as a blue function and my code is not working

Tags: mysql, sql

hello i am writing a triggers and when i enter the table name where it is requested it sees it as a blue function and my code is not working

```
CREATE TRIGGER soru2
   ON Transaction
   AFTER insert
AS
```

Transaction is blue  , I want to see it as a table

Comment: That;s not mysql create trigger syntax - is this question tagged correctly?

Comment: transaction is a reserved word. Change the name of the table "transaction" to something else.

Comment: For MSSQL use brackets `[Transaction]`, for Postgres use double quote `"Transaction"`, for MySQL use backticks `\`Transaction\``.